# Kendo Grid Export To Excel Save to a specific location

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-grid, export-to-excel

I am using angular 7 with kendo grid. When clicking export to excel, I need to save that file to a specific location in my PC. Is it possible with kendo grid export to excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save to a specific location, It's totally control by the browser. If the user needs to ask always download location. The user has to change the browser settings